# How to split tick label into multiple lines in pdfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can one ask pgfplot to split labels that are too long into multiple lines?

For example, I have a graph that depicts the answers to a questionnaire. The questions should be the labels of the Y axis, the `ticklabels` in PDFPlots' lingo. However many of these questions are long and the space for these labels should be limited to, say, 5 centimeters.

This is my current attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
Q & A & B & C
Q1 Very long question text that should be split in multiple lines & 0 & 1 & 3
Q2 Shorter question & 0 & 2 & 2
Q3 Another question with a long text & 2 & 1 & 1
}{\answers}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    y=0.8cm,
    y dir=reverse,
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\answers}{Q},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, width=5cm}, % << ERROR: width is not a recognized tikz key
]

\addplot [fill=red] table [x=A, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=B, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
\addplot [fill=green] table [x=C, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This document fails to compile with the following error: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/width', to which you passed '5cm', and I am going to ignore it.`

Is there a way to force each ticklabel to have a set width?

Comment: Try option `text width` instead of `width`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: indeed `text width` solves the issue. Could you submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgfplots` tick labels are `tikz` nodes, here you need option `text width=<dimension>`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
Q & A & B & C
Q1 Very long question text that should be split in multiple lines & 0 & 1 & 3
Q2 Shorter question & 0 & 2 & 2
Q3 Another question with a long text & 2 & 1 & 1
}{\answers}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    y=0.8cm,
    y dir=reverse,
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\answers}{Q},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, text width=5cm}
]

\addplot [fill=red] table [x=A, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=B, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
\addplot [fill=green] table [x=C, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With option `text width` or `align=left|center|right` used, you can also manually specify linebreaks by inserting `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

I create a new column, embedding content of Q column in `parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}



\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
        Q & A & B & C
        Q1 Very long question text that should be split in multiple lines & 0 & 1 & 3
        Q2 Shorter question & 0 & 2 & 2
        Q3 Another question with a long text & 2 & 1 & 1
    }{\answers}

    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/assign/.code={%
        \getthisrow{Q}\entry%
        \edef\entry{\noexpand\parbox{5cm}{\entry}}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry%
    }]{Qwidth}{\answers}
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    y=0.8cm,
    y dir=reverse,
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\answers}{Qwidth},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    ]
    
    \addplot [fill=red] table [x=A, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addlegendentry{A}
    \addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=B, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addlegendentry{B}
    \addplot [fill=green] table [x=C, y expr=\coordindex] {\answers};
    \addlegendentry{C}
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]